# Prove that this sequence converges to a point

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I encounter a problem about genetics equilibrium under the condition of mutation that needs me to ask for whether the following sequence converges to a point and if yes, what that point is.

---

$$\eqalign{
  & {a_1} = 0.5  \cr 
  & u = 0.7  \cr 
  & v = 0.55 \cr} $$

---

$$\eqalign{
  & {a_1} \in (0,1)  \cr 
  & {a_2} = {a_1}(1 - u) + v(1 - {a_1}){\rm{ }}  \cr 
  & u,v \in (0,1)  \cr 
  & {a_3} = {a_2}(1 - u) + v(1 - {a_2})  \cr 
  & {a_n} \to ?{\rm{ }} \cr} $$

when $$n \to \infty $$

---

The more important question is how is the answer derived? As a biomedical sciences student I only have background in Calculus I, II and linear algebra. No analysis background.

Answer (score 3):

We can rewrite your equations as:
$$a_2=a_1(1-u-v)+v$$
$$a_3=a_2(1-u-v)+v$$
and more generally as:
$$a_{n+1}=a_n(1-u-v)+v \tag{2}$$
the idea to solve such a relation is to first find a constant solution $c \in \Bbb R$:
$$c=(1-u-v) c+v \tag{2}$$
so:
$$c=\frac{v}{u+v}$$
Then by taking $(1)-(2)$:
$$(a_{n+1}-c)=(a_n-c)(1-u-v)$$
so $(a_n-c)$ is a geometric progression. Here as $|1-u-v| <1$ you have:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n-c)=0$$
so:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=c=\frac{v}{u+v}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the answer I want, with proof and clear reasoning.